# Toastr Impletmentation, after displaying error in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've checked a few posts on this site related to toastr and IE 10, that displays an error when run:

```
                    options = {
                        tapToDismiss: false,
                        toastClass: 'toast',
                        containerId: 'toast-container',
                        debug: false,
                        fadeIn: 300,
                        fadeOut: 1000,
                        extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                        iconClass: 'toast-info',
                        positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
                        timeOut: 5000,
                        titleClass: 'toast-title',
                        messageClass: 'toast-message'
                    };
                    toastr.success("Email Sent Successfully", "Email Sent");
```

The panel displays but then throws an error:

```
Line: 75 Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: focus
```

Which refers to jquery.min.js

```
{throw"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "+g;}
```

Comment: Is this only happening in IE 10? Can you create a JS fiddle to reproduce this?

Comment: This error means that you sent jQuery a selector that uses invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was interference with an old version of JQuery - used JQuery 10 and all seems OK.

Thanks